# I am trying to activate a window with pywinctl but something is wrong

Tags: python

```
import pywinctl as mm

win = mm.getAllAppsWindowsTitles()

try:
    aa = mm.getWindowsWithTitle(win.get('brave'))[0]
    aa.activate()
    print('worked')
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

this the code I am currently dealing with and it is really simple. I am a total newbie in python area and I think that is the problem. I just can't see what is wrong.

It should activate the brave with the current title from the win dictionary.

```
{'gjs': ['@!0,0;BDHF'], 'nautilus': ['rec'], 'brave': ['Ask a public question - Stack Overflow - Brave'], 'code': ['focus.py - rec - Visual Studio Code']}
list index out of range
```

this is the current output I am getting

I wanted it to activate the brave window

Comment: Holy moly, I found the solution and now I look back at it and laugh at myself. The problem is the the value of win.get('brave') is a list and it has these [ ]
I made some modifications to the list by converting it to a string then removing those [ ]
That's it.

Comment: you can answer you question , and accept your answer.